# Parallel Smith Waterman Algorithm implementation in CUDA - Last 2 rows not being computed

Tags: cuda, bioinformatics

I'm working on a parallel Smith Waterman algorithm implementation in CUDA, but have now run into some trouble. The last two rows of the score matrix are not being computed at all, they just show zero. Rest of the matrix is computed correctly.

The algo runs in two phases. First the number of threads increase to the size of the seq length, then shrink  back to 0. The kernels are called repeatedly with different number of threads and values of k. c is my score matrix, a,b the sequences and k is the kth anti diagonal (i+j=k). The values are offset by 1 as in Smith Waterman algo.

Here are my kernels:

```
__global__ void SmithWKernelExpand(int (*c)[arraySize+1], const char *a, const char *b, int *k)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x+1;
    int j = ((*k)-i)+1;
    int north=c[i][(j)-1]-1;            //Indel
    int west=c[i-1][j]-1;
    int northwest;
    if (((int) a[i-1])==((int)b[(j)-1]))
        northwest=c[i-1][(j)-1]+2;      //Match
    else
        northwest=c[i-1][(j)-1]-1;      //Mismatch
    //c[i][j] = max(max(north, west),max(northwest,0));
    c[i][j]=(*k);  //Print the number of anti diagonal - For Debugging
}

__global__ void SmithWKernelShrink(int (*c)[arraySize+1], const char *a, const char *b, int *k)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x+((*k)-arraySize)+1;
    int j = ((*k)-i)+1;
    int north=c[i][(j)-1]-1;            //Indel
    int west=c[i-1][j]-1;
    int northwest;
    if (((int) a[i-1])==((int)b[(j)-1]))
        northwest=c[i-1][(j)-1]+2;      //Match
    else
        northwest=c[i-1][(j)-1]-1;      //Mismatch
    //c[i][j] = max(max(north, west),max(northwest,0));
    c[i][j]=(*k);  //Print the number of anti diagonal - For Debugging
}
```

The output is:

```
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
0       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
0       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10
0       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11
0       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12
0       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: It seems fairly clear that the c[i][j] element of the output array is set by a particular thread ID.  Since the last two rows are not getting set, this is a function of the range of i, i.e. threadIdx.x +1, and the value is just whatever you are passing in *k.  So it seems quite obvious to me that only posting the kernel code is not enough.  We need to see your kernel invocations, as well.  Assuming you are not passing 0 in *k, one possibility is  you are not creating enough threads per block.  May also be a problem with data copying, which you also haven't shown.

Comment: Without a complete repro case, this question is unanswerable, and that has not been provided. Vote to close.